# Problem in understanding a code

Tags: c#

I'm not able to understand the code given below, so can anyone help me out in understanding the code.

```
private bool Compile(string path)
{
   bool result;

   using (CSharpCodeProvider prov = new CSharpCodeProvider())
   {
      CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters();

      string pathtoicon = "";
      if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.ico"))
      {
         pathtoicon = Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.ico";
      }

      param.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe" + " " + "/win32icon:" + "\"" + pathtoicon + "\"";
      param.GenerateExecutable = true;
      param.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
      param.EmbeddedResources.Add(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")+"\\points.dat");
      param.OutputAssembly = path;
      param.GenerateInMemory = false;

      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Deployment.dll");
      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
      param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");

      param.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
      CompilerResults compresults = prov.CompileAssemblyFromSource(param, Properties.Resources.Program);

      result = compresults.Errors.Count == 0;

      File.Delete(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\points.dat");
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Which part of code you are not able to understand?

Comment: param.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe" + " " + "/win32icon:" + "\"" + pathtoicon + "\"";
                param.GenerateExecutable = true;
                param.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
                param.EmbeddedResources.Add(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")+"\\points.dat");
                param.OutputAssembly = path;
                param.GenerateInMemory = false;

                param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
 can u help me to understand this part..

Comment: The code is actually creating an assembly.  Creating compiler parameters / options. - More details here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the above code is compiling a new .NET assembly using the available compiler classes in the .NET framework.

Here's some documentation that might help you:

[CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)

[CompilerParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx)